# Facebook retrieve specific user details using user id

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using fb php sdk. I am storing the fb user id in database when user signup using fb. But when I want to get the details back using fb user id it returns error. I want to return the values using the fb user id. Please help if anyone knows.

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(['app_id' => 'app_id', 'app_secret' => 'app_secret','default_graph_version' => 'v2.5']);    
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
if (! isset($accessToken)) {
    if ($helper->getError()) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
        echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
        echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
        echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
    } else {
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
        echo 'Bad request';
    }
    exit;
}
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);
try {
    $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,link,email,gender,cover,picture,friends');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
$user = $response->getGraphUser();
```

Comment: "it returns error." - and you believe that the exact error message would not be important?

Comment: Actually the id fb returns is not useful for that purpose because the id fb returns is not that id from which I can retrieve user's profile back. When I use that id which fb is returning it shows error. I don't know what is this happening. If fb has send the id then why can't I retrieve back the details using the same id request.

Comment: you misunderstood, read my comment again.